# Is there a non-abelian group of order 49?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Is there any non-abelian group of order $n=49$? I assume there should be at least one but I cannot find an example.

Comment: Actually any group of order $p^2$ for $p$ a prime is abelian. This is a nice exercise using the class equation.

Comment: $49 = 7^2$. For a given prime $p$ there are only two groups of order $p^2$, and they are both abelian. You should try proving this!

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the boldface text... that seems completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only groups of order $49$ are $\mathbb Z_{49}$ and $\mathbb Z_7\times \mathbb Z_7$ since $49$ is a square of a prime number.

Comment: both are cyclic though right?